# What is the meaning of doreka, doremo, and doredemo which is taken from dore?

Tags: interrogatives

So どれ means "which". When you add か,も,でも the "which" becomes "some,any,every" definitions which for "which" I don't quite understand.

Comment: I came here trying to remember the difference between nothing and anything, which I thought were either どれも or どれでも. These answers were very useful, but how does "nothing" fit into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

どれか is similar to 何か (something) or 誰か (somebody).
どれか means one among several options.
Example:
この中のどれか、頂戴できましょうか. 
Can you give me one of these?

どれも is similar to いつも (always) or どこも (everywhere).
どれも means all options.
Example:
どれも見事だ。They are all beautiful.

どれでも is similar to 誰でも (anyone) or 何でも (anything)
どれでも means any one among several options.
Example:
その中でどれでも好きなのを買いなさい。Buy whichever you like.

Answer (score 1):

- どれ which
- どれか which?
- どれも neither, unless used as どれもいい then it becomes "which ever" or if used with a verb どれも出来る = either or all (depending on how many things)
- どれでも which ever, or all and どれでもいい expresses indifference

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have options among several things, including selecting all or not at all.  That's the meaning (or... sense?) of dore in this case, in my understanding.  Adding the か or も or でも adds meaning to the option(s), which becomes any,some, or every.

(Note, may be incorrect in perspective of syntax.  Based on my recognition)